# Return index of JSON subarray if some keys in it contain specific values

Tags: php

I have the following JSON response structure:

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 14,
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 145,
        "from_id": 5435435,
        "to_id": 5435345,
        "date": 1550434860,
        "post_type": "post",
        "text": "sometext",
      },
      {
        "id": 144,
        "from_id": 43242342432,
        "to_id": 42342343243,
        "date": 1550365480,
        "post_type": "post",
        "text": "sometext2",
      },
      {
        "id": 143,
        "from_id": 543543543,
        "to_id": 534324645,
        "date": 1550355299,
        "post_type": "post",
        "text": "sometext3",
      },
    //more items of the same structure here...
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't even properly formulate it, but I need to write a function that conditionally returns `posts[0]` or `posts[1]` or `posts[2]`, etc. if it contains specific value of the key text. I.e. if the condition is `text == 'sometext'`, then the function must return `posts[0]` and so on.

I tried:

```
foreach ( $response->posts as $element ) {
    if ( 'sometext' == $element->text ) {
        var_dump($element);
        return $element;
    }
}
```

But it returns the whole contents of `posts[0]` and not the word `posts[0]`. I for the life of mine wasn't able to google up how to specify the index of the post instance in this chain: `$response->posts->index_of_posts`. Because the index is unknown and it's exactly what must be returned.

Please advice.

Comment: first of all `return $element;` exits the current Function scope, not just the loop, but it does end the loop at that point. Your better off building a new array with the stuff you want in the loop.

Comment: Oops, I edited the question...

Comment: The answer I put is still valid, the difference is if you want the first occurrence of a post with the text, or all of them.

Comment: The thing is that I need to get the word `posts[0]` in response and not the contents of `posts[0]`

Comment: There I updated my answer, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this `foreach` loop is not in a function then you should not be using `return` but can use `break` to stop the loop. Note by using a `foreach` in the form `foreach ($a as $key => $value)` you can get the index of the post as well. Try something like this:

```
$response = $json->response;
foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
    if ( 'sometext' == $element->text ) {
        break;
    }
}
echo "found text in post $key\n";
print_r($element);
```

Output:

```
found text in post 0 
stdClass Object (
    [id] => 145
    [from_id] => 5435435
    [to_id] => 5435345
    [date] => 1550434860
    [post_type] => post
    [text] => sometext 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mABEA)

If you are in a function and want to return the index, then you could just do this and use the index value to access the appropriate post outside the function:

```
foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
    if ( 'sometext' == $element->text ) {
        return $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm terribly sorry, I've only started using PHP for the first time in my life because I really need to write a script for my site and prefer doing this myself. I always try googling everything and only consult Stackoverflow as the last resort. What worked for me is:

`foreach ( $response->posts as $key => $element ) {
   if ( 'sometext' == $element->text ) {
    break;
   }
  }
  
  print_r('posts['.$key.']');`

Comment: @ErikGordon no need to apologise, if you can't find a solution to your problem then asking SO will almost always get you one. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
$keep = [];

foreach ( $response->posts as $key=>$element ) {
    if ( 'sometext' == $element->text ) {
         $keep[] = "post[{$key}]"; //expected output ["post[0]"] or ["post[0]", "post[30]", ... ] for more then one.

        //$keep[$key]= $element; //preserve keys
    }
}

print_r($keep);
```

Not to hard.

PS I am surprised you put the string first, which is actually the better way to do it, but least intuitive.  It's better because it avoids this:

```
 if ( 'sometext' = $element->text ) //assignment
```

Type errors in code, as this will throw a error (because you cant assign a value to a string) whereas this:

```
 if ( $element->text = 'sometext'  ) //assignment
```

Would change the value of `$element->text` with no error.

Cheers!

Comment: The raw response that I get from this code is `Array
(
    [0] => posts[0]
)` while I need only `posts[0]`.

Comment: As I said `The answer I put is still valid, the difference is if you want the first occurrence of a post with the text, or all of them.`  mine returns all of them, as that was not clear in the question.  To change it now I might as well delete it (someone else may find it useful, and i would have wasted my time), as that variation has been answered.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't quite get it... There can be only one occurence anyway, so that's fine. But instead of `posts[0]` I get the line `Array
(
    [0] => posts[0]
)` in my response, while I need ONLY the `posts[0]` part wthout everything else.

Comment: Then use the other answer!  Or should I rewrite mine to be identical, that was my point, anyway.

Comment: Sorry, the misunderstanding was on my part.

Comment: It's Kool...  ((>o.o)>>